# How to encrypt a big text file using AES algorithm, Hadoop and Java?

Tags: java, encryption, hadoop, aes

I have a big text file (100MB or more) and I want to use AES algorithm to encrypt the content of the text file using Hadoop and Java (Map/Reduce functions), but as I am new to Hadoop, I am not really sure how to start this. I found JCE (a Java library) where AES is already implemented but I have to provide 16 bytes text along with a key to generate a 16 bytes cipher text (encrypted output). My question is how to use this JCE/AES method to get my purpose done? How should I split my big input text file and What should I pass to the map method of Mapper class? what should be the key and value? What should be passed to the Reduce method? Any kind of starting point or code example would be greatly appreciated. (P.S. I am new to Hadoop and I just ran the wordcount problem on my machine, that's it.)

**EDIT 1:**

Actually, I have to do the following things:

1. split the input file in 16 bytes chunks.
2. for each chunk, I have to apply the AES algorithm to get 16 bytes cipher text and write the 16 bytes cipher text in the output file.
3. continue the process until the input file ends.

My question now is, how to parallelize it using Hadoop's Map and Reduce methods? what should be the key and how to accumulate the output cipher texts in the output file?

Comment: Actually, I meant to show that each line has 16 bytes of data may be. so that I can read 1 line (16 bytes) by 1 line and encrypt that using AES and Hadoop and then do the same thing for the next line. My confusion is how to do this using Hadoop. Please provide me with some guidelines if possible @owlstead

Comment: Is this just a learning exercise? If not, have you determined that this is the best approach?

Comment: @DaveNewton actually, this is the requirement as part of a project. I already have AES implementation in Pthread paradigm, now I have to do it in Hadoop and compare the results/speed ups etc. I will eventually do this for a huge file like 2 GB or more. But, I want to start with 10MBs of data first to see how it works. As I am new to Hadoop, I am struggling in the beginning to start. P.S, this might not produce good result, but the exploration is important for the comparison with another implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypting a large stream with a block cipher requires you to resolve a fundamental issue, completely irrelevant of how you actually split the work (M/R or whatever). The problem is the [cipher-block chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29). Because each block is dependent on the output of the previous block, you cannot encrypt (or decrypt) block N w/o first encrypting (or decrypting) block N-1. This implies that you can only encrypt the file one block at a time, starting with block 1, then block 2, then 3 and so on.

To work around the problem all encryption solutions do the same: they split the stream in chunks of adequate size (the right size is always a trade-off) and use some out-of-band storage where they associate each chunk with a startup nonce ([initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)). This way chunks can be ecnrypted and decrypted independently.

HDFS has a natural chunk (the block) and the access patterns on blocks are single threaded and sequential, lending itself to be the natural choice for encryption chunks. Adding the extra metadata on the namenode for the nonce on each block is relatively straightforward to do. If you do this for your own education, this is a fun project to tackle. Key management is a separate issue, and of course, as with any encryption scheme, key management is the actually **important** part while implementing the cipher is the trivial part.

If you are thinking at this for real world use, stop right now. Use an off-the-shelf encryption solution for Hadoop, of which there are several

Comment: Hi Remus, +1 for your thoughtful explanation.This is not for real world use.This is just for exploration e.g. how it affects the performance, pros and cons(mainly the performance analysis). Actually, the project I am working on has 2 parts. The first part is already done which is the parallelization of AES algorithm using C/Pthreads. I am using a 10MB file to encrypt using that AES implementation. Now, I am stuck in the 2nd part of the project which is to encrypt the same text file using Hadoop, Java and AES algorithm. In short, I want to encrypt a text file using Hadoop and AES algo.

Comment: With classical Hadoop you have to express your job as a map-reduce job. I'm not sure your job (encrypt a file) fits into M/R. What is the shuffle phase supposed to do? How do you map your map output to key-value pairs for reduce input to consume? I'm not saying is impossible, I'm saying is not a right fit. Hadoop 2.0, with the generic [YARN](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) container model would probably fit  better.

Comment: @RemusRusana, actually I am not really sure about the splitting of the file. If I use JCE library's AES class and its methods to encrypt the file, should not I just be able to generate a 128Kb key and give the text as input? and the output should be cipher text? I am just not sure how to fit this into Hadoop's Map/Reduce.

Comment: I have no idea about YARN. I am totally new in the Hadoop arena. Could you please explain why YARN might be a better fit? Should I look into YARN given that I have only couple of weeks to finish the project.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: I'm also facing this problem. You mentioned "Use an off-the-shelf encryption solution for Hadoop, of which there are several". Can you please share what are some such off-the-shelf solutions? I googled for "HDFS encryption" and "Hadoop encryption" and found almost nothing.